# Underscore no with templates undefined variable when running test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am using underscore templates to create some markup. I am using the no with approach so I am defining the variable setting.

So my template declarations look like so:

```
_.template('<div><%= data.title %></div>', { titles: title }, { variable: 'data'});
```

It works fine and evaluates the template fine, but when i run my unit test, it seems that, I get the error data is undefined.

By replacing data with either this, or self, or obj, it seems to work fine. I am wondering if there are any penalties to using those words like so:

```
_.template('<div><%= this.title %></div>', { titles: title }, { variable: 'this'});
```

OR

```
_.template('<div><%= this.title %></div>', { titles: title }, { variable: 'obj'});
```

OR

```
_.template('<div><%= self.title %></div>', { titles: title }, { variable: 'self'});
```

Thanks for the info.

Comment: Your template expects a property called `title`, but the data object has a property named `titles`.  Typo?

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting 'titles' as the key in your object, whereas the key that object contains is 'title'. Also, you need not pass the third parameter to `_.template`.

Since `_.template` returns a function, you can directly call this function by passing the object it needs as parameter as shown below:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/xDCkb/1/)

**JavaScript:**

```
var temp = {"title": "Hello world!"};
/* Approach 1
var t = _.template('<div><%= title %></div>');
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = t(temp);
*/
/* Approach 2 */
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = _.template('<div><%= title %></div>', temp);
```